# What does LEFT in SQL do when it is not paired with JOIN and why does it cause my query to time out?

Tags: sql, timeout

I was given the following statement:

`LEFT(f.field4, CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',f.field4) = 0 THEN LEN(f.field4) ELSE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',f.field4) - 1 END)=@DealNumber`

and am having trouble contacting the person that wrote it.  Could someone explain what that statement does, and if it is valid SQL?  The goal of the statement is to compare the numeric character in f.field for to the DealNumber. DNumber and DealNumber are the same except for a wildcard at the end of DealNumber.

I am trying to use it in the context of the following statement:

```
SELECT d.Description, d.FileID, d.DateFiled, u.Contact AS UserFiledName, d.Pages,   d.Notes
FROM Documents AS d
LEFT JOIN Files AS f ON d.FileID=f.FileID
LEFT JOIN Users AS u ON d.UserFiled=u.UserID
WHERE SUBSTRING(f.Field8, 2, 1) = @LocationIDString
AND f.field4=@DNumber OR LEFT(f.field4, CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',f.field4) = 0 THEN LEN(f.field4) ELSE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',f.field4) - 1 END)=@DealNumber"
```

but my code keeps timing out when I execute it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the `CASE` clause which is slowing things down, not `LEFT` per se (although `LEFT` may prevent the use of indexes, which will have an effect).

The `CASE` determines what should be compared with `@DealNumber`, and I think it does the following...

If `f.field4` does not start with a digit, use `LEFT(f.field4, LEN(f.field4))=@DealNumber`: that's equivalent to `f.field4=@DealNumber`.
If `f.field4` does start with digits, use `{those digits}=@DealNumber`.

This sort of computation isn't very efficient.

I would attempt the following, which makes the **large** assumption that a mixed string can be cast as an integer — that is, that if you convert `ABC` to an integer you get zero, and if you convert `123ABC` you get what can be converted, `123`. I can't find any documentation which says whether that is possible or not.

```
AND f.field4=@DNumber
OR (f.field4=@DealNumber AND integer(f.field4)=0)
OR (integer(f.field4)=@DealNumber)
```

The first line is the same as your `AND`. The second line selects `f.field4=@DealNumber` only if `f.field4` does not start with a number. The third line selects where the initial numeric portion of `f.field4` is the same as `@DealNumber`.

As I say, there is an assumption here that `integer()` will work in this way. You may need to define a `CAST` function to do that conversion with strings. That's rather beyond me, although I would be confident that even such a function would be faster than a `CASE` as you currently have.

Answer (score 1):

From the [doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html):

> **left(str text, n int)**
>
> Return first n characters in the string. When n is negative, return all but last |n| characters.

Comment: This is Postgre SQL.  Is that the same?  Specifically, why would this affect performance?

Comment: I don't use Postgre often, but it looks like the expression you've asked about has to be applied to each row of the result. And that may be _very_ slow.

Comment: That certainly could be part of it.  I feel like there is an issue using wildcards in C#'s cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue() method as well though.